# Django: How to make an API call just before browser tab close?

Tags: javascript, django

I am using Django v1.10 for an application where in need to send an API call just before browser close through crude javascript (don't want to use any library for sake) preferably. I've read about `window.unload` and `window.onbeforeunload`. The first one didn't seem to work at all. The second can work but it also gets executed when there is reload or redirection to another page (it works as it should but that is what I don't want). I've tried using `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` of Django which works only when a user has totally exit out of the browser (no browser process running). I've also seen answers on the web where people have suggested to open another window/tab of the browser through JS as the tab closes.

So in precise words, I want to make an API call just before browser tab close (not in any other situation).
Please help!